# Is there OpenID for PSN accounts?

Tags: node.js, openid, playstation

I am creating a website that contains a bracket system for a Rocket League tournament. I have set up OpenID for Steam, so that handles PC users. However I am trying to branch out to the console communities. Is there a way I can use OpenID to allow a user to sign into my website with their PSN login?

I mainly just need their ID to keep track of their scores, but if I can get a 
[PSN API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/psn-node) to work with an OpenID login it would be fantastic!

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

See:

- http://www.programmableweb.com/api/psn-sign

This may be what you need:

> This API allows people to use the Playstation Network SignIn for their
>   own sites. If a developer's site URL is allowed by Sony, they can set
>   their site as the returnURL by GET. This allows them to bypass Sony's
>   official External PSN Sign In page. The site forwards to a developer's
>   site on a successful sign in with a sessionId by GET. There is no
>   official public API to convert the sessionId into a user specific
>   value (like the PSN-ID). The API converts a valid sessionID into a
>   proper PSN-ID.

You didn't say what did you try so far so I don't know it you already tried that or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the docs and API link results in a 404 ( http://api.geekweb.org/psn/getid/). Is this because I need to use it in an OpenID system and not a GET request with no params?